# Error:A occurred configuring project ':app'. Android app

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My main project and my dependant project are in the same root directory

like

My root directory : AndroidProjects:

Android-nRF-Toolbox-master

Android-DFU-Library-release

The error reported :

Error:(24) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Project with path '..:DFULibrary:dfu' could not be found in project ':app'.

```
My build.gradle

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile project(':..:DFULibrary:dfu')
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/nrf-logger-v2.0.jar')
}

settings.gradle
include ':app', '..:DFULibrary:dfu'
```

Please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: Is DFULibrary:dfu a module parallel to your app module? If so, remove the first ":.." in your build.gradle file. use this: compile project(':DFULibrary:dfu')

Comment: Nope. The error was the incorrect name. I changed Android-DFU-Library-release to DFULibrary. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change  `compile project(':..:DFULibrary:dfu')` 
to `compile project(':DFULibrary:dfu')`.

Comment: Nope. I renamed Android-DFU-Library-release to DFULibrary. It worked. Thanks